# GLSL coordinate space?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Do I have to map `gl_Position` to be within `(-1,-1),(1,1)` for it to appear on screen, or what? i.e., is `(-1,-1)` the top left, and `(1,1)` the bottom right?

Before I was just using my library's `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView` and it took care of all the conversions for me, but I'm writing my own now and I'm not quite sure what I need to map the coords to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl_Position` is a 4-vector, so it has more than just those two elements, usually named x, y, z and w. When clipping, the coordinates are clipped to [-w, w], or in other words, after normalization (dividing each coordinate by w), to [-1, 1]. So normalized coordinates are clipped by the cube (-1, -1, -1) - (1, 1, 1) (unless you have defined more clip planes).

For more information on clipping, read

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node28.html

Comment: Right... I'm building a 2D HUD, so I forgot about Z, and W I always have set to 1.0 anyway. That makes sense. Thanks!